# Rail fence cipher get rid of loop-recur

Tags: encryption, clojure

I have this rail fence cipher code in Clojure with encryption and decryption. I need to get rid of loop-recur. How to **get rid of loop-recur** to make it more elegant? Thank you for helping.

```
(defn rail_fence_cipher [type key text]
      (let [counter (* 2 (dec key))
            groups (map
                     (fn [index]
                       (take-nth
                         counter
                         (drop index (range))))
                     (range counter))
            encrypt-text
            (take
              (count text)
              (loop [x (rest groups)
                     encrypt-text (take-while
                                  #(> (count text) %)
                                  (first groups))]
                (if
                  (= 1 (count x))
                  (concat encrypt-text (last x))
                  (recur
                    (rest (drop-last x))
                    (concat
                      encrypt-text
                      (take-while
                        #(> (count text) %)
                        (interleave (first x) (last x))))))))
            decrypt-text (->> encrypt-text
                             (map-indexed vector)
                             (sort-by second)
                             (map first))]
        (cond
          (= type "encrypt")
          (apply str
                 (map #(nth text %) encrypt-text))
          (= type "decrypt")
          (apply str
                 (map #(nth text %) decrypt-text))
          :else
          "Please enter a valid cipher mode.")))
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried to do that, so we can improve on it. Also if this version is giving you errors/stacktraces/... please add them to the question. If this version works and you want to remove the loop/recur it would also help why you want to remove it and what you think would be best to use instead.

Comment: Original code with comments is [here](https://i.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2rnwzf/20150107_challenge_196_intermediate_rail_fence/cnhqb3s/.compact)

Answer (score 3):

Style notes:

- Clojure uses *kebab-case*, not *snake_case*.
- `cond` can be replaced with [`case`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case) or [`condp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp).
- Your function is very long and hard to read- you should split it into more parts.
- Names of arguments could be more descriptive- `key` is actually number of rails.

Entry point can be rewritten as:

```
(defn rail-fence-cipher [action rails text]
  (case action
    "encrypt" (encrypt text rails)
    "decrypt" (decrypt text rails)
    "Unknown action."))
```

And first part can be rewritten without `recur` as:

```
(defn rails-pattern [rails]
  (concat (range rails)
          (drop 1 (range (dec rails) 0 -1))))

(defn encrypt [text rails]
  (->> (clojure.string/replace text #" " "")
       (map vector (cycle (rails-pattern rails)))
       (sort-by first)
       (map second)
       (clojure.string/join)))
```

Example (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher)):

```
(encrypt "WE ARE DISCOVERED RUN AT ONCE" 3)
=> "WECRUOERDSOEERNTNEAIVDAC"
```